# Compare value from input with variable - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a php script that gets the values between certain tags in an external file and echoes the tag values. My basic aim is to compare the variables to the value entered in an input form, then execute a function if the value is incorrect.

**PHP:**

```
function innerh($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fp = fopen("tags.text", "r");

if ($fp) {
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp);

    $parsed = innerh($line, "<tag>", "</tag>");
    echo $parsed;


    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form" action="function();" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="tags.text">
</form>
```

The detail is that I would like the value in `$fp = fopen("tags.text", "r");`  (tags.text) to be replaced with the value entered from a form.

Then if the value of the form does not match the value of a valid file, it executes a function.

Warning, if I replace the tags.text with a ?_GET, I get this error:
[image]

Note: I am new to PHP

Comment: Are you trying to say " Whatever text/filename given in the form input to be used in your PHP `fopen()` upon form submit" ?

Comment: @Makesh Yes, that is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form" method="get" action="your_file_open.php">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="tags.text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP :** [your_file_open.php]

```
$file_name = $_GET['subject'];
$fp = fopen($file_name, "r");
```

Do basic error handling on the $_GET[]

For more : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: I get this error: `Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/name/public_html/name.php on line 51`

Comment: echo $file_name. Is it empty ??

Comment: Fine now, forgot to put the php in an external file, so it worked properly when executed from the form with the php in an external file